# How do I get my formula to count unique values in my list of data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently maintaining a list of data of employees taking leaves in my company. Since an employee is able to take multiple numbers of leaves per month, there is a case of duplication of their names in the leave record list.

Each employees also comes with a rank of their own, e.g. Recruit, Private, Corporal. Which also duplicates throughout the whole list of data.

The table goes something like :

```
  A       B
1 NAME    RANK 
2 AAA     Recruit
3 BBB     Private
4 CCC     Corporal
5 AAA     Recruit
6 CCC     Corporal
7 DDD     Recruit
8 FFF     Recruit
```

How do I count the unique number of employees with the rank of "Recruit" from the list of the data?

I understand that you are able to count the number of UNIQUE employee through the following formula

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0),MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0))>0,1))
```

The expected result of my count for the number of unique employee rank "Recruit" should be THREE in the above scenario as there are 3 unique officers with the rank of "Recruit"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an extra condition for RANK in your formula similar to this:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B8=D2,MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0)),MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0))>0,1))
```

Here data range is A2:B8, D2="Recruit", and the formula is entered in E2 with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.